# How to remove overload popup

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have recently updated visual studio.   I use the keyboard a lot when working.

This new popup has started appearing when ever i copy code.  I normally do cntrl +c then use the arrow keys to move around to where i want to paste it.  I cant do that because this popup is blocking everything you have to hit esc or use the mouse to cancel it.

[image]

How to disable the overload popup.  I have looked everywhere in the settings i cant find it.

Visual studio 17 latest version (15.7.4)
Resharper is also running the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be changed in ReSharper options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

> Tools Menu => Options => Text Editor => All Languages => Uncheck
>   Parameter information

[image: Tool Menu => Options]

Comment: Doesn't seam to be helping.  I just restarted VS see if that causes it to reset.

Comment: What version your using

Comment: I'm using vs 2017 which works even without a restart. normally it should work without restart.

Comment: Doesn't help its still popping up Professional 2017 15.8.2.  Its a decent feature i guess.  But i dont think it should block the arrow keys there should be an easier way to have fade. having to grab the mouse is a pain.

Comment: whatever the suggestion it will hide when you use escape key. I'm using 15.7.3 which works perfect. I haven't felt the suggestion popup a burden yet.

Comment: It pops up constantly you cant move two spaces without it popping up thats a lot of escape keys just to copy paste some code.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party tools like resharper or any

Comment: Yes I have re-sharper do you think its that?  I just upgraded to 15.7.4  since you said it was working in 15.7.3 i guess it could have been a bug as well.

Comment: I would suggest to disable re-sharper and try it mostly it would be the problem

Comment: Upgrading visual studio didnt help

Comment: Did you try disabling resharper or any 3rd party tools

Comment: No because if its a resharper issue there should be a way to disable it